Kubuntu 22.04 on lutris in GTA 5 works only with integrated graphics card and on a regular integrated card the game runs slowly after 10 minutes
I have this problem, I have lutris on ubuntu 22.04, deb rockstar version, I run it this way
  ~/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/wine-ge-8-26-x86_64/bin/wine ~/Games/rockstar-games-launcher/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rockstar\ Games/Launcher/Launcher.exe

It only sees the integrated graphics card because the video memory size is 15 GB and it should be 8 GB
Games on Steam use a dedicated card, the exception is FIFA 22 where I had to enter in the launch options
DRI_PRIME=1 DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME="AMD Unknown (RADV GFX1102)" %command%

Because before entering it, it also used the integrated one, so I thought I would do the same with lutris and gave the command
DRI_PRIME=1  ~/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/wine-ge-8-26-x86_64/bin/wine ~/Games/rockstar-games-launcher/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rockstar\ Games/Launcher/Launcher.exe

And then, when the game was about to start, the Xorg Server was restarted and the following things appeared in the logs:
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] gmc_v11_0_process_interrupt: 9 callbacks suppressed
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:5 pasid:32807, for process GTA5.exe pid 20763 thread GTA5.exe:cs0 pid 20826)
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800030017000 from client 10
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501431
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: SQC (data) (0xa)
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vmid:5 pasid:32807, for process GTA5.exe pid 20763 thread GTA5.exe:cs0 pid 20826)
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800030017000 from client 10
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: CB/DB (0x0)
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:57:46 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x0
[pią lis  1 16:58:21 2024] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout, signaled seq=63023, emitted seq=63024
[pią lis  1 16:58:21 2024] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process CrGpuMain pid 20362 thread SocialClub:cs0 pid 20483
[pią lis  1 16:58:21 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
[pią lis  1 16:58:21 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:21 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
[pią lis  1 16:58:22 2024] [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] [drm:gfx_v11_0_cp_gfx_enable.isra.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to halt cp gfx
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: MODE1 reset
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU mode1 reset
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU smu mode1 reset
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x00000081FEB00000).
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] [drm] VRAM is lost due to GPU reset!
[pią lis  1 16:58:23 2024] [drm] PSP is resuming...

My spec is
kernel = 6.8.0-45-generic
lspci -k
lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b5 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1513
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b6
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1513
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b8
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ba
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14cd
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b7 (rev 01)
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b9 (rev 10)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14b9 (rev 10)
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH SMBus Controller
        Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH LPC Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1679
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167a
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167b
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167c
        Kernel driver in use: k10temp
        Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167d
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167e
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 167f
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1680
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 12)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev 12)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 7480 (rev c3)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 231d
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab30
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 231d
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5017 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Sandisk Corp Device 5017
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
        Kernel modules: nvme
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        DeviceName: Onboard LAN Brodcom
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
        Subsystem: AzureWave Device 5471
        Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
        Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be
77:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt (rev 0a)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 231d
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
77:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 231d
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
77:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. VanGogh PSP/CCP
        Kernel driver in use: ccp
        Kernel modules: ccp
77:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161d
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
77:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161e
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
77:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 60)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
        Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp6x
        Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt, snd_sof_amd_vangogh, snd_sof_amd_acp63
77:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
        DeviceName: HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
78:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 161f
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
78:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d6
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
78:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d7
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
78:00.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 162e
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 20af
        Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
        Kernel modules: thunderbolt

Games on Steam use a dedicated card, the exception is FIFA 22 where I had to enter in the launch options
Let's assume they can use an integrated graphics card, but then after 10 minutes of driving a car in the game it starts to stutter very badly as if it was 1 FPS.
